# jQuery conflicting on Blogger widget

Tags: blogger, jquery

Hi I'm very new to this so forgive me for my nobbishness.

Recently I tried to install a responsive blogger menu, this is the code

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script> <script type='text/javascript'> // <![CDATA[ $(function() { var offset = $("#FloatingSocialButtons").offset(); var topPadding = 15; $(window).scroll(function() { if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) { $("#FloatingSocialButtons").stop().animate({ marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding }); } else { $("#FloatingSocialButtons").stop().animate({ marginTop: 0 }); }; }); }); // ]]> </script> <style> #FloatingSocialButtons { position: absolute; left: -100px;  background-color: #F2F2F2; border: 1px solid #D8D8D8; border-right: 0; z-index:9; border-radius:10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; } #FloatingSocialButtons div { margin: 5px 0 0 0; } </style>   <div id='FloatingSocialButtons'> <center> <div style='margin:0px 0 0px 10px;'><div id='fb-root'></div><script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1'></script><fb:like font='' href='' layout='box_count' send='false' show_faces='false'></fb:like></div> <div><a class='twitter-share-button' data-count='vertical' data-lang='en' href='http://twitter.com/share'>Tweet</a><script src='http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js' type='text/javascript'></script></div> <div><script src='http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js' type='text/javascript'></script><g:plusone size='tall'></g:plusone></div> <div style='margin-top: 15px;'><a data-pin-config='vertical' data-pin-do='buttonPin' href='http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='data:post.url' '><img src='//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png'/></a> <span style='margin-left:-44px;'><a data-pin-config='vertical' data-pin-do='buttonBookmark' href='//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/' style='outline:none;border:none;'></a></span> <script src='http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js' type='text/javascript'></script></div> <br /> <p style=' line-height:0px; font-size:10px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;'><a href='www.tipstricksisland.com/2013/05/new-smooth-floating-social-bookmarking-blogger-2013.html' style='color:#CAC8C8;'>Get This</a></p> </center></div>
```

And its not working, when i asked the author he said I have jquery conflict issue but cannot help me further. I don't know how to do this. Please look at my blog and tell me which widget is causing the issue http://dota2android.blogspot.com

Thank you for your time

Comment: why are you using jQuery 1.3?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: I told you, i'm very new to this stuff. I only heard the word Jquery today :(  That is why I linked to my blog. So can you please do it noob friendly. Like what should i do ? Sorry I'm trying my best to read about it much as possible

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a jQuery Conflict issue, you should be [using jQuery in NoConflict Mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

This means that if some library or object has already claimed the use of jQuery's `$` keyword, it will still perform as expected.

```
 $.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
    // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply can you please tell me in which line should i place that code ? > Really new to this stuff <

Comment: I feel that the problems you are experiencing are advanced, and numerous. If you are unable to reduce the problem to a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE) you may not be at the level required to debug and fix these issues. Stack Overflow questions should only solve one problem per question, so if you need advanced, personalised assistance you may need to enlist the help of a professional web developer.